# Binding Listbox to List<object> in WinForms

Tags: c#, list, winforms, listbox

What's the simplest way to bind a Listbox to a List of objects in Windows Forms?

Comment: what is your platform? silverlight? WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET? the answer kinda depends on this knowledge.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DataSource property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx):

```
List<SomeType> someList = ...;
myListBox.DataSource = someList;
```

You should also set the `DisplayMember` property to the name of a property in the object that you want the listbox to display.  If you don't, it will call `ToString()`.

Comment: How would I go about removing an item of SomeType from the Listbox via selection?

Comment: `someList.Remove((SomeType)myListBox.SelectedValue);`  (In WinForms)

Comment: Hello. It is working for me as long as I don't add anything to collection. As soon as I change my collection items in list box does not update. Even after assigning dataSource after chaning items in collection.

Comment: If you are binding via a viewmodel, then the List must be encapsulated in an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: The question is about WinForms.

Comment: To handle updates to the collection in WinForms, use `BindingList<T>`.

Comment: Just had the same question but wondered why there is no `DataSource`... if you use *System.Windows.Controls.ListBox* the equivalent is `ItemSource`

Answer (score 17):

Pretending you are displaying a list of customer objects with "customerName" and "customerId" properties:

```
listBox.DataSource = customerListObject;
listBox.DataTextField = "customerName";
listBox.DataValueField = "customerId";
listBox.DataBind();
```

Edit: I know this works in asp.net - if you are doing a winforms app, it should be pretty similar (I hope...)

Comment: The Windows.Forms.Listbox has other members; see below.

Comment: @surfmuggle ... and the `DataBind()` method doesn't exist, I guess?

Answer (score 17):

Binding a [System.Windows.Forms.Listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) Control to a list of objects (here of type dynamic)

```
List<dynamic> dynList = new List<dynamic>() { 
            new {Id = 1, Name = "Elevator", Company="Vertical Pop" },
            new {Id = 2, Name = "Stairs", Company="Fitness" }
};

listBox.DataSource = dynList; 
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Comment: I know this question is not related, but: how would you access the `Company` member?

Comment: @Wolf you can't unless you dig through the list yourself; omitting the ValueMember setting so that the SelectedValue is the entire object would probably be easier

Answer (score 6):

Granted, this isn't going to provide you anything truly meaningful unless the objects have properly overriden `ToString()` (or you're not really working with a generic list of objects and can bind to specific fields):

```
List<object> objList = new List<object>();

// Fill the list

someListBox.DataSource = objList;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ListBox1.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
ListBox1.DataTextField = "FieldProperty";
ListBox1.DataValueField = "ValueProperty";
```

Please refer to [**this**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx) article for detailed examples.

Answer (score 3):

I haven 't seen it here so i post it because for me is the best way in winforms:

```
    List<object> objList = new List<object>();

    listBox.DataSource = objList ;

    listBox.Refresh();
    listBox.Update();
```

Comment: Oh, my God...thank you! It's been 12 years since I've worked in WinForms and I've been stuck for almost two hours trying to get this &@%$ ListBox to behave.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main routes here:

1:  `listBox1.DataSource = yourList;`

Do any manipulation (Add/Delete) to yourList and Rebind.
Set DisplayMember and ValueMember to control what is shown.

2:  `listBox1.Items.AddRange(yourList.ToArray());`

(or use a for-loop to do `Items.Add(...)`)

You can control Display by overloading ToString() of the list objects or by implementing the listBox1.Format event.

Comment: How do you rebind?

Answer (score -2):

For a UWP app:

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" DisplayMemberPath="Source" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Results}"/>
```

C#

```
public ObservableCollection<Type> Results
```

Comment: Question was tagged WinForms.

Comment: @LarsTech didn't notice that since it wasn't part of the title or text, but I got here by looking for answers to the same question for UWP, perhaps someone else will too and find this answer useful.