# drop down list binding

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table which has an Id and a name field. I usually bind the name to the dropdownlist but I was told that any dml should be on the Id so how can I use the name in the dropdownlist and at the same time still use the Id?

Comment: A very similar question was just answered a little while ago - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675067/binding-listbox-to-listobject)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675067/binding-listbox-to-listobject

Answer (score 2):

Use DataTextField and DataValueField when binding:

```
ddlList.DataSource = thesource;
ddlList.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlList.DataValueField = "ID";
ddlList.DataBind()
```

Where ID and Name are fields in your data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dropdownlist's `Text` field to the name and the `Value` field to the ID.