# How can a dynamic be used as a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

How can I use a dynamic as a generic?

This

```
var x = something not strongly typed;
callFunction<x>();
```

and this

```
dynamic x = something not strongly typed;
callFunction<x>();
```

both produce this error

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'x' 
could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What can I do to `x` to make it legitimate enough to be used in `<x>`?

Comment: Your code is confusing. It looks like you're trying to pass a variable as a type parameter? This won't work anyway. It needs to be a type.

Comment: @M.Babcock - even when converted to a type the same error is issued. For example: `Type t; t = LegitimateObject.GetType(); callFunction<t>();` produces the same error.

Comment: No not a type as in `System.Type` a type as in `string` or `int` directly. Variables cannot be used as type parameters.

Comment: `var x` does not mean that the variable `x` is not strongly typed. The compiler infers (guesses if you prefer) the type of the expression to the right of `=` and makes it the type of `x`. If The compiler thinks that the expression is of type `string` then `var x` means exactly the same as `string x`. Note also that this happens at compile time, not at runtime!

Comment: You example code doesn't make sense: Consider your code if x *were* strongly typed: `string x = "X";`.  You don't call `CallFunction<x>()` or `CallFunction<typeof(string)>()`; you call `CallFunction<string>()`  This doesn't make sense unless CallFunction has a string parameter or return value;  A more likely call would be `string x = CallFunction<string>();` or `CallFunction<string>(x)`.  Can you give an example of the function you'd like to call?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @phoog - There is no try ;) I did manage to achieve this with the immaculate help of JonSkeet. See his answer and the comments below for some better context.

Comment: [populating a list control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466468/2932052) seemed a good use case for this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use type inference to sort of trampoline the call:

```
dynamic x = something not strongly typed;
CallFunctionWithInference(x);

...

static void CallFunctionWithInference<T>(T ignored)
{
    CallFunction<T>();
}

static void CallFunction<T>()
{
    // This is the method we really wanted to call
}
```

This will determine the type argument at execution time based on the execution-time type of the value of `x`, using the same kind of type inference it would use if `x` had that as its *compile-time* type. The parameter is *only* present to make type inference work.

Note that unlike Darin, I believe this *is* a useful technique - in exactly the same situations where pre-dynamic you'd end up calling the generic method with reflection. You can make this *one* part of the code dynamic, but keep the *rest* of the code (from the generic type on downwards) type-safe. It allows *one* step to be dynamic - just the single bit where you don't know the type.

Comment: Hah! This works, well with a little adaptation. Pure genius. I love it. The problem is that with your current definition T must be a reference type to use it as a parameter later in the `CallFunction`. To improve on this, I made these edits: `static void CallFunctionWithInference<T>(T ignored) where T : class` and `static void CallFunctionWithInference<T>(T ignored) where T : class`. Thanks again! I wish I had more than +1.

Comment: @TravisJ: Is that because `CallFunction` itself has a constraint? You didn't tell us that in the question :) Without the constraint on `CallFunction` it should be fine though.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the omission :) The constraint in `CallFunction` is an initialization (down the line) of an EF DbSet in the form of `this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();` which is inside a generic repository called from a using statement. At the time I did not realize it would affect the outcome in this way or I would have included it.

Comment: The first comment should read "The problem **on my end** is that..."

Comment: @TravisJ: Righto - that makes sense :)

Comment: I bountied this answer because of its awesomeness.

Comment: I experienced some odd behavior using this when trying to make `x` with `Activator.CreateInstance`. I have struggled for a few days with it and was hoping you could provide some insight? I am getting an exception: outer: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` inner: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.SymbolTable.GetOriginalTypeParameterType(Type t) +10`. Here is the code: `dynamic AnyObject = Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", "MyAssembly.Models.DbModels." + entityType).Unwrap();CallWithInference(AnyObject);` What did I do wrong?

Comment: @TravisJ: I think it would help if you could create a new question for this, with a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I made a complete example, but was unable to exactly reproduce the problem. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12096695/1026459

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell what exactly are you trying to do. But if you want to call a generic method with a type parameter that is the same as some object, you can't do that directly. But you can write another method that takes your object as a parameter, let the `dynamic` infer the type and then call the method you want:

```
void HelperMethod<T>(T obj)
{
    CallFunction<T>();
}

…

dynamic x = …;
HelperMethod(x);
```

Comment: Wow.. this is awesome.. A subtle difference is that when `x` is null, type inference mechanism fails here. If `x` is strongly typed, the method call itself wont fail. Just something to have in mind..

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The whole point of generics is compile-time safety which means that they must be known at compile-time. And the whole point of dynamics is that you don't need to know the exact type at compile time and use runtime dispatching => it's the absolutely exact opposite of generics. So don't waste your time => once you get the dynamic/reflection path you can forget about generics and compile-time safety. You will have to walk that path till the end.

So to answer your question:

> What can I do to x to make it legitimate enough to be used in ?

The only thing you could do is to use a type that is known at compile-time, otherwise you cannot use generics.

Comment: Well, you kind of can use generics with a type that is not known at compile time, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because `x` is not a type. You need to specify a type as a *type* parameter.

In fact, you *can* use `dynamic` as a type parameter if you use it correctly:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

dict.Add("Item1", 123);
dict.Add("Item2", "Blah");
```

This compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to make this work is to make your anonymous type a real type.

So instead of

```
var x = new { Value = "somevalue", Text = "sometext" };
```

You need to do

```
class MyClass
{
    string Text, Value;
}
....
var x = new MyClass() { Value = "somevalue", Text = "sometext" };
//this should work now
callFunction<MyClass>(x);
```

Comment: Note that `x` is still strongly typed in the first code snippet; however, the type is anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the function like this

```
callFunction<dynamic>();
```

If your function is defined as

```
public void callFunction<T>(T arg) {
    ...
}
```

You can simply call it with

```
callFunction(x);
```

C# is able to infer generic type parameters in many situations.