# Type instantiation from an assembly in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, types

Is it possible to do something like this?

1. Create a class and put it in an assembly, e.g

   ```
   namespace some
   {
       public class foo{
           ..etc
   }
   ```
2. Load it into the current appdomain

   ```
   Assembly.LoadFrom("some.foo.dll");
   ```
3. Get the type out

   ```
   Type t = Type.GetType("some.foo");
   ```

Basically is there anyway to get the actual type into t?

Comment: This might be similar to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12096695/1026459

Comment: With "actual type", you mean an instance?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Maybe you want to do `var a = Assembly.LoadFrom("some.foo.dll");` and then `var t = a.GetType("some.foo");`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was trying to articulate :) I think the mistake I made was I assumed Assembly.Load would load types directly into the appdomain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. I think you want to instantiate the type.

This calls the public default constructor:

```
// specify the full name and assembly name, to make sure that you get the some.foo
// from the assembly in question.
Type t = Type.GetType("some.foo, some.foo");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Look at the overloads to call other constructors.

Comment: The CreateInstance doesn't create a fully typed foo though, you have to cast it if you want to pass it as foo with type foo.

Comment: Cast to what? When you loaded the assembly dynamically, you usually don't know the type. Else you would just call the constructor directly. It would make sense to have an interface at least, but the question is not about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to instantiate the object. For example, to instantiate using the default constructor:

```
Type.GetType("Foo").GetConstructor().Invoke();
```

To instantiate using a constructor taking a string, use:

```
Type.GetType("Foo").GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) }).Invoke(new [] { "bar" });
```

Comment: When you know `Foo`, why don't you just call `new Foo()`?

Comment: Good point. I'll remove the variable from the examples because, as you say, we assume we do not know foo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("SomeAssembly.dll");
assembly.GetType("SomeType");
```