# Select current date and display results sql

Tags: c#, sql

I am a newbie into this and I don't know how to do this.

I have SQUL Server database, where I have records for many dates. It is like this:

```
id | run | date
1  | 12  | 02.22.2014 14:23:34
2  | 22  | 02.22.2014 18:20:25
3  | 05  | 02.22.2014 20:58:30
4  | 08  | 02.23.2014 08:28:44
5  | 10  | 02.23.2014 12:53:28
6  | 18  | 02.23.2014 14:23:34
```

What I need is to give a list of all dates, no repeat, and show them in a listbox, using winforms in C#. For instance, in this case I would have just 02.22.2014 and 02.23.2014. In that case, if I select 02.22.2014 I would like to calculate the average 'run' (in this case is 13) and show it in a label.

What is the query I should use and how can I populate the listbox with the dates?
What I've read for mysql there is a query like `WHERE DATE('Date')=CURDATE()`.

Comment: Are you using WPF? or winforms? or even web  like asp.net mvc ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using winforms

Comment: What database engine do you use. SQL Server, oracle,... Depending on the database engine, there are different functions to group by date

Answer (score 1):

This query should have it:

```
select 
    avg(run) 
from 
    tableName 
group by DATEPART(year, [date])
        ,DATEPART(month, [date])
        ,DATEPART(day, [date])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(run), CAST(date AS DATE) FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```

Then you will get the result something like this

- 13 02-22-2014
- Next avg and date and so on.

Then you map the results with your listbox.

Comment: This is a good answer, tho, you'll have to cast the first `date` as DATE as well as in the group by to get the result you show.

Comment: @paqogomez yes that is true. Missed that one.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.  +1.  Hopefully i'll get some points too. :)

Comment: thanks, how can i populate the listbox now? shall i create a list of object first?

Comment: @user2962759 Yes you can map the sql result to a object then make a list of that object. Then map it into listbox. Then when selecting a listbox get that selecteditem and take the avg value and populate it to your label /textbox. if you dont know how to populate the listbox you can google for it. There a ton of examples.

Comment: @user2962759 here is an example how to bind the list to a listbox.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675067/binding-listbox-to-listobject

Answer (score 0):

To fill the list:

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DATE], 105) FROM TableName";
```

To get de average:

```
string sql = "SELECT AVG(run) FROM TableName WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DATE], 105) = @SelectedDate";
```

Please, review the [documentation for the Convert function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx) for different date/time formats conversion.