# How to pass selected list value from popup into a textbox using C# webforms?

Tags: c#, list, textbox, selectedvalue

I have a table called Vendor that has two columns: VendorNum & VendorName.

Is there a way to create a list or a listbox or a listview that when a button is clicked, this vendor list will pop up. Then the selected popup list's row will pass the selected VendorNum into a textbox that's in the parent page..

I only know GridView has the select row option, but is it a proper way to put the gridview into a Listbox so the list can be scrolled up/down all within a fixed box?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [ListBox.SelectValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [ListBox.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) properties

Comment: k, but first how do you setup both columns within one ListBox?

Comment: @user3486647 There are several ways of populating a ListBox and the specific code will depend on your data format. Here is a basic example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675067/binding-listbox-to-listobject

Comment: i'm using webforms, not winform. 
Thanks, Saul, but the link still confuses me.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. I have changed my answer to point at the webforms version of that control. Webforms was designed to be very similar to winforms, that link about populating a winforms listbox is still relevant for the webforms version