# Bind Winforms ListBox collection to List<object>

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have a class containing details of my customer.

```
class CustomerData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        { return _Name } 
        set 
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

   // Lots of other properties configured.
}
```

I also have a list of `CustomerData` values `List<CustomerData> MyData;`

I currently `databinding` an individual `CustomerData` object to `textboxes` in the below way which works fine.

```
this.NameTxtBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", MyCustomer, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

I'm struggling to find a way to bind each object in the list `MyData` to a `ListBox`.

I want to have each object in the MyData list in displayed in the ListBox showing the name.

I have tried setting the `DataSource` equal to the `MyData` list and setting the `DisplayMember` to "Name" however when i add items to the `MyData` list the `listbox` does not update.

Any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: Have you checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675067/binding-listbox-to-listobject ?

Comment: Yes i have tried that. However when i add items to my List the ListBox does not update.

Comment: winforms does not use observation system. therefor you have to push object to listbox itself.

Comment: Ah found it. Instead of List<T> i needed to use BindingList<T>. This allows the ListBox to update as the collection is modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that `List<T>` will not allow updating of a ListBox when the bound list is modified. 
In order to get this to work you need to use `BindingList<T>`

```
BindingList<CustomerData> MyData = new BindingList<CustomerData>();

MyListBox.DataSource = MyData;
MyListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

MyData.Add(new CustomerData(){ Name = "Jimmy" } ); //<-- This causes the ListBox to update with the new entry Jimmy.
```